# A function that is both log-supermodular and submodular?

Tags: reference-request, order-theory, lattice-orders, vector-lattices

Functions that are log-supermodular and submodular do they have some special name? Or any special properties? Any references? Is the function below log-super-modular *and* sub-modular?

Consider $\mathbb{R}^2_{+}$ as a lattice with the coordinate-wise order, $(a,b)\ge (c,d)$ iff $a\ge c$ and $b\ge d$.

Remember a function is super-modular if $f(x\vee y)+f(x\wedge y) \ge f(x) + f(y)$ where $\vee$ is the coordinate-by-coordinate maximum and $\wedge$ is the coordinate-by-coordinate minimum.

It is *sub-modular* iff $-f$ is super-modular. It is *log* super-modular if $\log(f)$ is super-modular.

If $f$ is twice differentiable, it is super-modular if and only if it has positive cross-partial derivatives: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j\partial x_k}\ge 0$ for all $j\neq k$.

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2_{++}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by:

$$ f(x,y)=\dfrac{y^2}{x(x+y)(x+2y)} $$

We have that $$\partial_{xy}f=-\dfrac{2 (3 x^2 y + 9 x y^2 + 7 y^3)}{(x + y)^3 (x + 2 y)^3}<0$$ and also $$\partial_{xy}\log(f)=\dfrac{3 x^2 + 8 x y + 6 y^2}{(x + y)^2 (x + 2 y)^2}>0$$.

So $f$ is both submodular and log-supermodular in its domain (the positive orthant).

Comment: I really don't know what this question is about, but are the tags suitable for it?

Comment: I'd be grateful find someone could find better tags but these were the best I could find. Supermodularity only makes sense if one has a lattice/order structure involved.

Comment: If you think the question is not clear, please post a comment so I can improve it. Simple downvoting does not help.

Comment: I got a ping from your comment. Not sure if it was directed to me or if I got it just because I was the previous commenter, in any case I didn't down vote you.